# поднять django на хосте beget

Tags: django

не могу поднять сайт django1.11 python3.5.2
на сайте выдаёт такую ошибку
Raw process output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/passenger40/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py", line 320, in <module>
    app_module = load_app()
  File "/opt/passenger40/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py", line 61, in load_app
    return imp.load_source('passenger_wsgi', startup_file)
  File "/home/s/snoy123/.local/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 172, in load_source
    module = _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 693, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "passenger_wsgi.py", line 6, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/home/s/snoy123/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/home/s/snoy123/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 22, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/home/s/snoy123/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/s/snoy123/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/s/snoy123/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 110, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/home/s/snoy123/.local/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'energo.settings'
```

структура проекта такая...

```
/eimp.com.ua
    energo/
          energo/
                __init__.py
                settings.py
                urls.py
                wsgi.py
          polls/
                models.py
                admin.py
                ...
          db.sqlite
          manage.py
    punlic_html/
          .htaccess
    tmp/
          restart.txt
    passenger_wsgi.py
    publik [link]
```

в файле .htaccess прописано так

```
PassengerEnabled On
PassengerPython /home/s/snoy123/.local/bin/python3.5
```

в файле passenger_wsgi.py так

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append('/home/s/snoy123/energo.com.ua/energo')
sys.path.append('/home/s/snoy123/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'energo.settings'
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

понимаю что скорее всего проблема в путях, перепробовал кучу вариантов, ничего не помогает.

Comment: Определитесь, eimp.com.ua или energo.com.ua

Comment: домен eimp.com.ua , но проект делался (startproject energo)

Comment: увидел спасибо!